# Xlib: sequence lost in reply type 0x2

Tags: multithreading, xlib, motif

i had an occurrence of this error (Xlib: sequence lost in reply type 0x2) in a program i'm maintaining (i'm not the original developer).

I'm far from being an expert in Xlib programming, and i included motif in the tag only because this program was written using that toolkit. 
I did some research before posting, and found out that this error is probably due to a thread (different from the UI's one) which is trying to update the UI itself. Searching in the code i found some calls to XTestFakeKeyEvent and XtIsManaged which i'm sure are used in a different thread from the UI.

My question is: could these two functions originate this error?

I would think that only functions that do update the GUI (e.g. set the text of a label) could cause problems of that sort (and these 2 functions don't seem to directly impact the gui), but i honestly don't know....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XTestFakeKeyEvent is most likely the culprit.  It injects a key press/release event, which could mess up the event queue.

XtIsManaged will not cause a change, but may give the wrong result if the managed state is changed during it's execution.

Comment: Thanks! In the meanwhile i've started to modify the code. Basically i'll add a pipe, adding it as one of main loop's sources of events (with XtAppAddInput if i recall correctly) and then i should be good to go.